# Year value error from PHP date()

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-range

Given a start and end date, I need to generate an array with year and week values.
For example:

Start Date: **2013-01-01**

End Date: **2013-02-23**

Generated Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [week] => 01 [year] => 2013 ) 
[1] => Array ( [week] => 02 [year] => 2013 ) 
[2] => Array ( [week] => 03 [year] => 2013 ) 
[3] => Array ( [week] => 04 [year] => 2013 ) 
[4] => Array ( [week] => 05 [year] => 2013 ) 
[5] => Array ( [week] => 06 [year] => 2013 ) 
[6] => Array ( [week] => 07 [year] => 2013 ) 
[7] => Array ( [week] => 08 [year] => 2013 ) )
```

Here is the code I'm using to generate this:

```
public static function getYearWeekRange($startdate, $enddate) {
    $array = array();
    $starttime = strtotime($startdate);
    $endtime = strtotime($enddate);
    while ($starttime <= $endtime) {
        $year = date('Y', $starttime);
        $week = date('W', $starttime);
        $array[] = array('week' => $week, 'year' => $year);
        $starttime = strtotime('+1 week', $starttime);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

---

My problem is that when I generate certain date ranges, I don't get the correct year value at the start of the 2013 year. For example:

Start Date: **2012-01-01**

End Date: **2013-02-23**

In this case, where it should have an subarray with year = 2013 and week = 01, it actually has it's year value equal to 2012.

If I were to switch the start date to 2013-01-05 for example, then there is no problem.

Can anyone offer a solution that would guarantee that my year and week values are always correct?

Comment: Thanks, the example in the link fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem using the following:

```
public static function getWeekRange($startdate, $enddate) {
    $array = array();
    $p = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($startdate), 
        new DateInterval('P1W'), 
        new DateTime($enddate)
    );
    foreach ($p as $w) {
        $array[] = array('year' => $w->format('o'), 'week' => $w->format('W'));
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as apparently it wasn't useful, but you still haven't actually explained what the problem was very clearly.